# Spring Formatters not registered when some class extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

The desired steps to a valid `Formatters` registration are:

1. First of all, the method [addWebMvcConfigurers](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java#L42) located in [WebMvcConfigurationComposite](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java) should registrate all the web configurers. That includes the `formatters`.
2. After that, when some component needs to `@Autowired` a `ConversionService` instance, the method [mvcConversionService](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java#L602) located in [WebMvcConfigurationSupport](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java) obtains a `ConversionService` instance and register all the existing `formatters` on it before return the instance.

However, if a `@Configuration` class extends the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` abstract class, some component is trying to `@Autowired` a `ConversionService` instance before the `formatters` have been registered in the Spring context, so the `addFormatters` method doesn't include any `formatters` on it.

I've just create the following proof of concept that uses Spring Boot to reproduce this issue:

https://github.com/jcagarcia/proofs/tree/master/spring-security-and-formatters

If you execute [this proof of concept](https://github.com/jcagarcia/proofs/tree/master/spring-security-and-formatters) using the `mvn compile spring-boot:run` command, you could check that the `Create Pets` view shows an enum value without apply the conversion to String.

[image]

Seems like the component that requires the `ConversionService` instance is the `ContentNegotiation` that is beeing `@Autowired` in the [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java#L376).

A simple work-around is to `@Override` the [setContentNegotiationStrategy](https://github.com/jcagarcia/proofs/blob/master/spring-security-and-formatters/src/main/java/org/springframework/roo/petclinic/config/security/SecurityConfiguration.java#L54) method in our [SecurityConfiguration](https://github.com/jcagarcia/proofs/blob/master/spring-security-and-formatters/src/main/java/org/springframework/roo/petclinic/config/security/SecurityConfiguration.java) class without include the `@Autowired` annotation. *(The proof of concept includes this work-around commented)*

After that, execute this proof of concept again using the `mvn compile spring-boot:run` command and you could check that the `Create Pets` view shows an enum value with a valid format applied.

[image]

I think this is not the best solution because the `ContentNegotiationStrategy` is not beeing `@Autowired` anymore.

Any idea about how can I solve this problem?

Feel free to checkout the proof of concept and execute it to reproduce the issue.

Best Regards,

Comment: I've just created the following issue in the Spring Security repository https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4202

Comment: I've just created the following ussue in the Spring Framework issue tracker https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15239 Seems like Rossen Stoyanchev can reproduce the issue so we're waiting for the Spring Boot developers answer.